# Remove all formatting from text

Tags: html, css, text, formatting

Is there anyway to remove all formatting from text within a certain class?

for example i have text brought from a database and displayed like so -

```
<p class="text">
Blah BLAH blah
</p>

<p>
blah **BLAH** blah
<p>
```

I need it so the same text can be shown twice but only one with the formatting that it is saved with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove formatting? dont think you can remove styles.If you have to remove define a new class and override them.

```
<p class="text">
Blah BLAH blah
</p>

<p class="noFormatting">
blah **BLAH** blah
<p>.

.noFormatting{
 font-style:normal;
 font-weight:normal;/* any other properties you want to ovveride! */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a custom class(with no formats) or use inline formatting that has the highest priority:

```
<p class="noFormat">
...
</p>


or 
<!-- inline -->
<p style="font-size: , font-family: , font-weight: , margin: , padding: , text-align: ">
...
</p>
```